Adjoints of linear maps between modules
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: M \times N \to R$ be a bilinear form. Let $f: M \to M$ be an $R$-Linear map. Does there necessarily exist a right adjoint of $f$, meaning an $R$-linear map $g: N \to N$ such that for all $m \in M$, $n \in N$ we have $\langle f(m), n \rangle = \langle m, g(n) \rangle$?
The motivation behind this is taken from the theory of distributions: A distribution is just a continuous linear functional on the space $X = C_c^\infty$ of smooth functions with compact support. Hence we get a natural pairing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: X' \times X \to \mathbb{C}$. We have a notion of derivation on $X$. And now, we define the notion of weak derivative on $X'$ by requiring $\langle \phi, f' \rangle = - \langle \phi', f \rangle$. So in this case, we define a notion of weak derivative by taking the negative adjoint of the usual derivative. The question is how much this can be generalized.

I doubt it to be true in general : see e.g https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem. If an abstract proof was available, I think a proof without referring to Hilbert space structure would be known

@MahammadYusifov I don't quite see how the claim of my question would imply the Riesz representation theorem

This is not true in general. For example, take $R=N=\mathbb Z$ and $M=\mathbb Q$, and the bilinear form $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$ given by multiplication. For any $x\in\mathbb Q-\mathbb Z$ we have the endomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb Q$ given by multiplication by $x$. Thus $\langle f(a),b\rangle=abx$, so the only possible adjoint $g$ would be division multiplication by $x$ on $\mathbb Z$.

I think the adjoint would also be multiplication by $x$ on $\mathbb{Z}$, which is still impossible though.

Above answer is just perfect, this one is to supplement my comment and maybe would be interesting to read.
The comment about Hilbert space is faulty because inner product is not bilinear, but otherwise $R = \mathbb{C}$, $M,N = H$ a infinite dimensional hilbert space, $f$ a continuous linear map and $m\mapsto \langle f(m),n \rangle$ for fixed $n$ is a linear functional on $H$. I was saying that in that case, proving the adjoint requires the structure of $H$ in the sense that proof isn't just algebraic, which is what you asked.
Another example : Let $V = C([a,b])$ be the vector space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and integral of multiplication as bilinear form. A theorem says any linear functional $l : V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t  $l(f)\geq 0$ if $f\geq 0$ is of form $l(f) = \int_{[a,b]}f(x)d\mu(x)$ for some finite Borel-measure $\mu$ for each $f\in V$ . You can find a proof here.
It is really technical and long, because construction doesn't only involve algebra, although $M,N = V$ are $R-$modules.
Shortly, I didn't say claim is true or not, but thought it is too good to be true to be only algebraic. Hoprefully, I didn't make mistakes
